# how to add events into google calendar automatically from another app?

Tags: android, gmail, google-calendar-api

I want to make an app that keeps timetable of a college student. I want the app to be able to add a student's classes timings into google calendar about 4-5 classes in a day of 1hr. is it possible to do? the app will have calendar permissions of course.

there is another app that does this, that i know of, but it sends email to gmail account which is then read by google and the events get added automatically like flight times etc. is this the only way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar) to achieve your goal. For inserting events into a calendar you need to hit the [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) endpoint, check how it works by playing around with the ***Try this API***.

There is also a [Java Example](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#examples_1) and a [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java), which can give you an idea on how to make the calls, before adapting that code into your Android app.